# QSpinBox move cursor after the last existing character

Tags: c++, qt

I have a spinbox with a default 0 in it. After I click on the spinbox the cursor needs to move after the 0 inside the box. The function bellow is not producing any suitable result.

```
void CSpinBoxExtra::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
  if(this -> value() == 0)
    QSpinBox::lineEdit() -> setCursorPosition(QSpinBox::lineEdit() -> text().length());
}
```

Anyone see any solution here?

Edit:

[ 0] -> click -> [ I0] (current)

[ 0] -> click -> [ 0I] (desired)

Comment: When you say *after I click on the spinbox*, do you mean the line edit or the arrow buttons? Cause on Windows 7, when I click on the line edit, it goes where I click, which in most cases is at the end.

Comment: On the line edit.

Comment: What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The QSpinBox does not have such a direct method. However, it gives you access to the intrinsically used QLineEdit.

```
QSpinBox spinBox;
auto lineEdit = spinBox.lineEdit();
```

In turn QLineEdit does have such methods. you can [get the text](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#text-prop), then get its size and set the position with [setCursorPosition(int)](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qlineedit.html#cursorPosition-prop).

```
auto endPos = lineEdit->text().size();
lineEdit->setCursorPosition(endPos);
```